# Dogs paw red with scar, maybe washed too much?

Tags: dogs, wound-care

I observed things like the wound in the picture on my dog's paw. I take them out to the garden 2-3 times a day and every time I come, I wash their paws and dry them with a towel. does anyone know what this is? Could it be because of drying or washing?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you use for washing? Soap? Is the dog sensitive if you touch rhis areas? Do you dry between the toes also? Is this area dry when you touch or wet (not directly after cleaning)?

Comment: And welcome to petsSE :) Plus another question: does the dog licks it paws more than usual?

Comment: I only use water for washing and always dry between the toes. He is now sensitive when I touch there, he is not licking his paws more than usual. And thank you for kind greeting :)

Comment: I would assume, that washing the paws 3 times a day iss too much and one need to give something back to the paws. The skin produces fatty things to protect the skin, so maybe there is some ointment. But I am not an expert and this is the cause I do this as comment instead of an answer. But I assume there are eyperts in dogs here, who may know how to prevent the scars.

Comment: Today I started to use fatty balm and will try to reduce the washing amount. I hope this goes well and the scars go away. If so, I'll post it here for the record. Thank you for your help :)